# automate linked integration runtime to data factory

Tags: azure-devops, securestring, azure-data-factory

I have a data factory that will be sharing IR set up and resource ID is ready and permission to ADF is granted. I am trying to automate IR set up on the second data factory that will be receiving the integration runtime as linked integration runtime from the adf with shared runtime. I am trying to set this up using bicep, but I am having trouble understanding some of the properties in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories/integrationruntimes?tabs=bicep#credentialreference

1. is it possible to automate creating a linked integration runtime for a data factory?
2. What are examples of SecureString, CredentialReference, Key for the linkedintegrationruntime object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**is it possible to automate creating a linked integration runtime for a data factory?**

You can **only automate self-hosted Integration Runtime** setup on an Azure virtual machine by creating a `Self-host IR template`.

**What are examples of SecureString, CredentialReference, Key for the linkedintegrationruntime object?**

**SecureString:** The value of string will be hidden with asterisks ' * ' during Get or List API calls, eg. password="**********".

**CredentialReference:** The reference to the authentication information for Integration Runtime.

**Key:** It is an integration runtime authentication keys in the form of secure string.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/integration-runtimes/create-linked-integration-runtime

Comment: I think this should now be possible via az cli? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73027070/azure-data-factory-link-a-shared-integration-runtime-via-az-cli