# azure data factory - link a shared integration runtime via az cli

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cli

I have two data factories. The "shared" data factory has an integration runtime that I'd like to share with the "client" data factory via az cli.

I am able to do this via the portal by navigating through the "shared" data factory \ Integration Runtimes \ Edit \ Sharing tab and selecting "Grant permission to another Data Factory or user-assigned managed identity".

My problem comes when trying to achieve the same via az cli. I have tried the following sequence of two az cli commands:

```
az datafactory integration-runtime self-hosted create --factory-name adf-rb-shared `
  --integration-runtime-name shir01 `
  --resource-group rg-adf-shared 

az datafactory integration-runtime linked-integration-runtime create `
  --factory-name adf-rb-shared `
  --integration-runtime-name shir01 `
  --resource-group rg-adf-shared `
  --data-factory-name adf-rb-client-001
```

The first command seems to work and does create a new integration runtime in the "shared" data factory.

However, the second command gives the following error:

> (UnsupportedVersionForSharableIR) None Code:
> UnsupportedVersionForSharableIR Message: None Target:
> /subscriptions/sub-number-here/resourceGroups/rg-adf-shared/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adf-rb-shared/integrationruntimes/shir01

Anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Steps to create ***Shared Integration Runtime***.

1. Create a self-hosted integration runtime.
2. Share the self-hosted integration runtime with other data factories.
3. Create a linked integration runtime.

As you created a self-hosted integration runtime after that Get the integration runtime authentication key and register a node.

To Retrieve the authentication keys for an integration runtime.

```
az datafactory integration-runtime list-auth-key --factory-name
                                                 --integration-runtime-name
                                                 --resource-group
```

When you register the integration runtime node, you utilise this key.

**The self-hosted integration runtime installation and registration.**

- From the Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime website, download the installer for the self-hosted integration runtime.
- Launch the installer to set up the locally hosted integration.
- The authentication key that you got in the previous step should be used to register the new self-hosted integration.

The data factory needs access to the self-hosted integration runtime that you registered and created provide it permission. Add contributor role

Run the following command to create a linked self-hosted integration runtime:

```
az datafactory integration-runtime linked-integration-runtime create --factory-name
                                                                     --integration-runtime-name
                                                                     --resource-group
                                                                     [--data-factory-name]
                                                                     [--location]
                                                                     [--name]
                                                                     [--subscription-id]
```

Comment: The original question was asking about how to install an ADF and link to an existing integrated runtime on another ADF via CLI but your answer was about how to install the SHIR, which wasn't what was asked.